# on clicking href link a new image gets loaded

Tags: jquery, css, image

I have a 6 images in a data folder and a html page with links for each image. By default first image is loaded. Now clicking on second link, second image should load replacing the first one. Same way for the rest of the image links. Is it possible at all?

Comment: Upload the code that you tried so far.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read the http://stackoverflow.com/tour and have a look at these help topics http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic and http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Looking at your questions history, I think your in a high risk of a question ban. A well deserved question ban.

Comment: This guy actually doesn't try much himself. But, anyways, I got him what he wants.

Comment: @Deadpool I salute your commitment

Answer (score 2):

For what you want you need to do that with javascript. To be precise, jQuery would be easier for you to use.

I think this example will help you out:

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<style>
div{width:200px;height:200px;}
img{width:190px;height:190px;}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div><img src="http://i.imgur.com/3UimJUz.jpg"></div><br/>
<button id="but1">Link 1</button>
<button id="but2">Link 2</button>
<button id="but3">Link 3</button>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#but1").click(function(){
 $('img').attr('src','http://i.imgur.com/3UimJUz.jpg');

});
$("#but2").click(function(){
 $('img').attr('src','http://i.imgur.com/tn1IO3v.jpg');
});
$("#but3").click(function(){
 $('img').attr('src','http://i.imgur.com/BfC9rYf.jpg');
});
});

</script>

</body> 

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Universal example:

```
<img src="" id="loader">
<a href="#" class="clicker" img-url="http://domain/imgs/1.jpg"> 1</a> 
<a href="#" class="clicker" img-url="http://domain/imgs/2.jpg"> 2</a> 
<a href="#" class="clicker" img-url="http://domain/imgs/3.jpg"> 3</a> 
<a href="#" class="clicker" img-url="http://domain/imgs/4.jpg"> 4</a> 

<a href="#" class="clicker" img-url="http://domain/imgs/N.jpg"> N</a> 

<script>
  $(document).on("click", ".clicker", function(){
    $("#loader").attr ("src", $(this).attr("img-url"));
    return false;
  })
<script>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Please check this. I think this might help you. Thank you.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var imageList = ['https://www.w3schools.com/css/paris.jpg', 'https://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg', 'https://www.w3schools.com/css/rock600x400.jpg', 'https://www.w3schools.com/css/lights600x400.jpg', 'https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_forest.jpg', 'https://www.w3schools.com/css/pineapple.jpg'];
    $('img').attr('src',imageList[0]);
    $("button").click(function(){
      var buttonId = $(this).attr('id').split('-');
      
      $('img').attr('src',imageList[buttonId[1]]);
    });
});
```

```css
.imageContainer{width:300px;height:300px;}
.imageContainer img{width:280px;height:280px;}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="imageContainer">
    <img src="">
  </div>
  <button id="click-1">Image 1</button>
  <button id="click-2">Image 2</button>
  <button id="click-3">Image 3</button>
  <button id="click-4">Image 4</button>
  <button id="click-5">Image 5</button>
</body> 

</html>
```